Error mounting /dev/sda1 at /media/ on Ubuntu 24.04
How can I fix the below error? It works pretty well in the previous version of Ubuntu, when I updated Ubuntu 24.04, after that the error mounting occurred.

I tried to fix this with a recommended solution like installing ntfs-3g command, but this cannot find the hard drive.

This error message is useless. We need more information. Open a terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T, run lsblk -f and post the output in an edit to your question.

Is this a Windows NTFS formatted partition?  And used with Windows? Then Windows fast startup/hibernation or the need for chkdsk may be the issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation  Note that Windows updates may turn fast startup back on recreating issue.
